# PHP string Formatting

Tags: php, formatting

Using PHP I want to format a number(7) like in 6 digits 000007

I had done this via `printf` Function but wanted to store it in a variable how can I do so.

Below mentioned code not working, giving output as :000007 and printing it on screen:

```
$gensubjectid=printf("%06d\n", $origionalsubjectid);
```

Suggest.

Comment: `sprintf()` should do what you need

Comment: printf returns the length of the outputted string

Comment: Dude printf of sprintf not working 
Below is appropriate solution.
$input = 7;
str_pad($input, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 7):

Use `sprintf` - it's identical to `printf` but it returns the formatted string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: [spirntf](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
$unformattedNumber = 7;  
$formattedNumber = sprintf('%06d', $unformattedNumber);
```

Or you can try this ([str_pad](http://www.php.net/manual/bg/function.str-pad.php)):

```
$input = 7;
str_pad($input, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str_pad().

```
$invID = str_pad($invID, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Or

Use sprintf: http://php.net/function.sprintf

```
$number = 51;
$number = sprintf('%10d',$number);
print $number;
// outputs 0000000051
```

$number = 8051;
   $number = sprintf('%10d',$number);
   print $number;
   // outputs 0000008051

Comment: This is what I want I am getting accurate result as I want it is really very help full.